# C++11 transform with shared_ptr to a vector and class

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, transform, shared-ptr

I am trying to apply transform to a `shared_ptr` and store to a `shared_ptr` while also using a function in a class.

I created this example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class MyClass {
public:
    int factor = 0;
    MyClass(const int factor_) : factor(factor_) {}

    shared_ptr<vector<int> > mult(shared_ptr<vector<int> > numbers) {
        shared_ptr<vector<int> > result(new vector<int>() );

        transform(numbers->begin(), numbers->end(), result->begin(),
            [this](int x){ return factor * x; });

        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<vector<int> > numbers(new vector<int>());
    shared_ptr<vector<int> > res(new vector<int>());
    MyClass times_two(2);

    numbers->push_back(1);
    numbers->push_back(2);
    numbers->push_back(3);

    res = times_two.mult(numbers);

    cout << "{";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < res->size(); ++i)
        cout << res->at(i) << ", ";
    cout << "}";    

    return 0;
}
```

As can be seen [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e99572bbe89b29c7) this causes a segmentation dump. Any help on how I could resolve this so that the output yields `{2, 4, 6, }`?

Note that I use the lambda because I need it in my full implementation.

I tried also to replace,

```
transform(numbers->begin(), numbers->end(), result->begin(),
        [this](int x){ return factor * x; });
```

with

```
transform((*numbers).begin(), (*numbers).end(), (*result).begin(),
        [this](int x){ return factor * x; });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    shared_ptr<vector<int> > result(new vector<int>() );
```

You construct a new, empty vector.

```
    transform(numbers->begin(), numbers->end(), result->begin(),
        [this](int x){ return factor * x; });
```

Since `result` is empty, `result->begin()` returns the ending iterator value. `std::transform` copies the input sequence, applies the transformation lambda, and writes the transformed result to the output iterator.

Since the vector is empty, there's nothing to write to. You're running past the end of the empty array, resulting in undefined behavior and memory corruption.

In this case, simply preallocate the output array, since you know what its size should be, in advance:

```
shared_ptr<vector<int> > result(new vector<int>(numbers->size()) );
```

Now, this will create the output array of the correct size, `begin()` will return an iterator to the beginning of the array, and `std::transform()` will happily scribble over the array.

If you really wish to avoid the extra overhead of value-initializing the new array, just to have it overwritten, you can use `reserve()` to preallocate the array's final size, then use a `std::back_insert_iterator` for the output iterator, instead of passing in `begin()`.

Comment: Thanks! That works. I used `reserve` and `back_inserter()`. The solution can be found [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/188945e985a51137).